# How to sort an empty array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How do you sort this empty array using foreach loop to output these 25 numbers in order?

Example outcome would be: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4

```
    <?php
    $array = array();

    for($counter = 0; $counter <=25; $counter++){

        $die = rand(1, 10);
        $int[$counter] = $die;     
        echo " $die ";  
    }

    sort($die);
    foreach ($die as $value) 
    {
       echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$array = array();` `$int[$counter] = $die;` `sort($die);` Ummmmm

Comment: You're defining `$array` as an array; treating the undefined `$int` as an array; but trying to sort `$die` (which is an integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <=25; $i++) {
    echo $array[] = rand(1, 10);
}

sort($array);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; 
}
```

Comment: how to you lay them out horizontally?